# How to bring classic styles back in VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I really like the new studio. Just don't pluck out your eyes fonts and styles.
I am trying to bring everything back

1. I installed this theme: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DarkTheme2019
2. I changed the font here: **Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor** to **Consolas**
3. But I can't find how to remove unnecessary syntax highlighting! In VS2019 there were such options:

[image: screen1]

or

[image: screen2]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Control syntax highlighting in tools -> options -> fonts and colors (text editor)  You can change most foreground and background colors.
For the ones you don't want to see, set them to match the text colors.